# What is this sun blocker in film making?

Tags: filming

In the making of Django Unchained, I noticed some people running behind the camera team. These people are holding something that looks like a sun blocker.

Video that shows it in use is [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3-VCVLtlBQ&t=635)

I haven't been able to confirm that or find out what this actually does.

Can anybody tell me?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the angle, I'd say it's a reflector. The line of people on the right are standing with their backs to the sun, it's probably there to bounce a bit of fill light on to their faces, so they're not silhouetted.

Comment: Thank you. Could you perhaps take a quick look at the full scene where it's shown in action? I guess this way it can better be estimated: https://youtu.be/e3-VCVLtlBQ?t=635

Comment: Looking at that I'd say definitely reflector, but probably for the foreground character near the camera mostly. Once again, the camera is looking into the sun, it's to get a bit of fill light into the shadows.